# How to write image of a floppy disk to a flash drive?

Tags: windows, linux, usb, floppy

I have created an image of a floppy disk by executing:

```
dd if=/dev/fd0 of=/home/myFloppy.img
```

My floppy disk is no more working now. So I am thinking now if it's possible to write the image of that floppy to a flash drive and then I may boot my machine from the flash drive.

My machine's BIOS has the option of 'Boot from USB'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 5 of the website mentioned by Darren seemed to be a solution to my problem but it did not work for me.

After a little browsing the method shown in "[Creating a bootable USB thumb drive - Page 2](http://www.lowfps.com/creating-a-bootable-usb-thumb-drive/page-2) " did the magic for me.

Comment: An answer that no longer works because the link is dead and there's no real information in the answer.

Comment: I found an archived copy on the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20100411071050/http://www.lowfps.com/creating-a-bootable-usb-thumb-drive/page-2

Answer (score 1):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) can do that very easily.

Just run it and there should be a box that defaults to "ISO", choose "Floppy" from the drop-down menu and then browse to your image. It does it in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

This website provides several methods to do this, including methods of converting a floppy image to USB boot.  There appears to be additional steps other than raw writing the floppy image directly to the USB drive.

http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm